# How to create dynamic menu from MySQL database with Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have been trying to load the menu from a database using Spring JPA and Spring Boot with a MySQL database.

I have to load only active menu from database. I have tried with JPQL, i.e. findByActiveTrue() method of JPA, but I get all records.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menu_tbl")
//@Cacheable
//@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)

public class Menu implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "menu_description")
    private String menuName;

    @Column(name = "menu_link", nullable = false)
    private String link;

    @Column(name = "menu_css")
    private String css;

    @Column(name = "menu_ico")
    private String icon;
     
    @Column(name = "active")
    @
    private Boolean active;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    @OrderBy("id ASC")
    private Set<Menu> children;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Menu parent;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMenuName() {
        return menuName;
    }

    public void setMenuName(String menuName) {
        this.menuName = menuName;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getCss() {
        return css;
    }

    public void setCss(String css) {
        this.css = css;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public Set<Menu> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<Menu> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public Menu getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Menu parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

}
```

Repository

```
public interface MenuRepository extends JpaRepository<Menu, Long> {
    
    
    List<Menu> findByActiveTrue();

}
```

And getting output

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "menuName": "Customer",
        "link": "/customer",
        "css": null,
        "icon": null,
        "active": true,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "menuName": "Add Customer",
                "link": "/addCustomer",
                "css": null,
                "icon": null,
                "active": false,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "menuName": "View Customer",
                "link": "/viewCustomer",
                "css": null,
                "icon": null,
                "active": false,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menu_tbl")
public class Menu {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "menu_description")
    private String menuName;

    @Column(name = "menu_link", nullable = false)
    private String link;

    @Column(name = "menu_css")
    private String css;

    @Column(name = "menu_ico")
    private String icon;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private Boolean active;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "main_id",
            nullable = true)
    private Menu mainMenu;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mainMenu", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Menu> children = new HashSet<>();
}
```

And

```
List<Menu> findAllByMainMenuIdAndActiveIsTrue(Long mainMenuid);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikita but this didn't work and As per your suggestion we have to pass mainMenuId which seems a hardcoded logic. I don't want to pass  any parameter in method my requirement is, if the record is active then only record should be populate which handle by 'active' field

Answer (score 0):

Enable `spring-jpa-show-sql=true` to watch which queries are being executed against your database from your IDE console. That will give you more insights on how you'll write your method.